Finding polynomials in $\ker(T)$ and nullity of $T$
Edit: Turns out I completely misinterpreted my question, here's the "correct" working out.
We can define the kernel of $T$ as.
$$
\ker T=\{ \mathbf{v}\in V|[\mathbf{v}]_{B}\in null([T]^{B}_{C}) \}
$$
Where $[T]^{B}_{B}$ has already been defined as:
[T]^B_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
So we just need to solve for $null[T]^{B}_{B}$
$$
[T]^B_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\sim_{rref
}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We get this by swapping $R_{2}\to R_{3}$ and $R_{1}\to R_{1}+2R_{2}$ then $R_{2}\to-1R_{2}$
Substituting to find our basis:
$$
x_{3}=0\text{ and }x_{1}=-x_{2}, x_{2}=x_{2}
$$
Giving us:
$$
\mathbf{v}=x_{2}\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\ker T=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Does this solve for $\ker T$? I'm not sure where to go from here to find the polynomials and nullity.

How was $T$ defined as? I can infer from what you have written, but I think you should explicitly write it out in the beginning.

I should've done that, my bad, made the changes!

What does the $=0$ mean at the end of your definition?

Yes, I should've checked my work more thoroughly before I sent it, fixed the notation errors + the actual errors. Thank you!

For any finite-dimensional vector space(s), we can always turn a linear transformation into a matrix by choosing an ordered basis. The columns of the matrix are then just the result of applying the transformation to each basis element of the domain, written in the basis of the codomain.
For $\Bbb R_2[x]$, we can choose $B = (1,x,x^2)$ as an ordered basis. Then,
$$
T(1) = 1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}_B \\
T(x) = 0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}_B \\
T(x^2) = -x^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}_B \\
$$
and so the matrix of $T$ in the basis $B$ is
$$T_B =  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}_B$$
Can you take it from here?

I completely misinterpreted my question but I did eventually find my $\ker T$ just not sure how to transform it back into the polynomials to find the polynomials in $\ker T$

The get from a column vector representation back to a polynomial, you just need to multiply each coordinate by the corresponding basis polynomial. If your basis is $B$ as defined in my answer, then $(a,b,c)^T = a + bx + cx^2$.
